# How to fix TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting this error and I've no idea how to resolve it. It is long file so I put the function that creates problem. 'Pari' is a class that I've imported from another file. I'll add another information if it's not sufficient.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beamline.py", line 379, in <module>
    f_twiss = beamline.TwissProp(i_twiss)
  File "beamline.py", line 169, in TwissProp
    det_x = np.linalg.det(element.M[0:2, 0:2])                        # linalg--linear algebra
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Idea about element: Magnets is a subclass of Element.

```
    class Pari(object):
          ''' main class'''
          def __init__(self, line, twiss=None, init_mom=None, part_type = 'electron'):
              self.offset = zeros(6)

              if not(isinstance(line, basestring) or           # basestring check whether it is instance or not
                     isinstance(line, beamline.Line)):
                     raise ValueError('Must provide a beamline')

    class Magnets(Element):
      ''' Magnets class discribe the function of magnets. it is a subclass of Element :) '''
      def __init__(self, name, L=1, P=1, S=0, aper=0, aper_shape= 'elliptical', K=0, tilt=0):
          self.K = K                                   
          self.tilt = tilt
          Element.__init__(self, name, L, P,S, aper, aper_shape)
def DriftMmat(L):
    '''Return the M matrix for a drift'''
    M = np.array([
        [1, L, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, L, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        ])
    return M
    class Quadrupole(Magnets):
      def calMmatrix(self, P=-1):
          ''' M matrix of the element'''
          if P == -1:
             P =self.P
          L = self.L
          if self.K ==0:
             self.M = DriftMmat(L)
          elif self.K < 0:                 
               K1 = np.sqrt(-(self.K))
               C_H = np.cosh(K1*L)
               S_H = np.sinh(K1*L)
               C = np.cos(K1*L)
               S = np.sin(K1*L)
               if hasattr(self, 'M') and not self.M == None:  # hasattr->true if string is the name of one of object's attributes         
                  self.M -= self.M
                  self.M[0,0] = C_H
                  self.M[0, 1] = S_H/K1
                  self.M[1, 0] = K1*S_H
                  self.M[1, 1] = C_H
                  self.M[2, 2] = C
                  self.M[2, 3] = S/K1
                  self.M[3, 2] = -K1*S
                  self.M[3, 3] = C
                  self.M[4, 4] = 1
                  self.M[5, 5] = 1
               else:
                    self.M= np.array([
                      [C_H, S_H/K1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [K1*S_H, C_H, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, C, S/K1, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, -K1*S, C, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                       ])
          elif self.K > 0:
               #Brho = B_mul_rho*P
               #K = np.sqrt((self.B/L) / Brho)
               K1 = np.sqrt(self.K)
               C_H = np.cosh(K1*L)
               S_H = np.sinh(K1*L)
               C = np.cos(K1*L)
               S = np.sin(K1*L)
               if hasattr(self, 'M') and not self.M==None:
                  self.M -= self.M
                  self.M[0, 0] = C
                  self.M[0, 1] = S/K1
                  self.M[1, 0] = -K1*S
                  self.M[1, 1] = C
                  self.M[2, 2] = C_H
                  self.M[2, 3] = S_H/K1
                  self.M[3, 2] = K1*S_H
                  self.M[3, 3] = C_H
                  self.M[4, 4] = 1
                  self.M[5, 5] = 1
               else:
                    self.R = np.array([
                    [C, S/K1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [-K1*S, C, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, C_H, S_H/K1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, K1*S_H, C_H, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                    ])
```

my code:

```
def TwissProp(self, ini_twiss):
    '''Propagates an initial twiss object ('ini_twiss') through the
    lattice.
    For each element, the twiss calculated at its downstream end are
    stored as an attribute of that element.  The twiss output at the
    end of the lattice are returned from this function.'''
    sum_phix, sum_phiy = 0, 0
    final_twiss = copy.deepcopy(ini_twiss)
    finalgammax = (1+ini_twiss['alphax']**2) / ini_twiss['betax']
    finalgammay = (1+ini_twiss['alphay']**2) / ini_twiss['betay']

    for element in self:
        element.twiss = copy.deepcopy(final_twiss)

        if element.__class__.__name__ == 'Pari':
           element.TwissProp()
           continue

        det_x = np.linalg.det(element.M[0:2, 0:2])                        # linalg--linear algebra
        det_y = np.linalg.det(element.M[2:4, 2:4])

        deltaphix = np.arctan2(element.M[0, 1] , \
           (final_twiss['betax']*element.M[0, 0] -
               final_twiss['alphax']*element.M[0, 1]))
        deltaphiy = np.arctan2(element.M[2, 3] , \
           (final_twiss['betay']*element.M[2, 2] -
               final_twiss['alphay']*element.M[2, 3]))
        sum_phix += deltaphix
        sum_phiy += deltaphiy

        betax  = final_twiss['betax']
        alphax = final_twiss['alphax']
        gammax = finalgammax
        betay  = final_twiss['betay']
        alphay = final_twiss['alphay']
        gammay = finalgammay

        final_twiss['betax'] = (
           (element.M[0, 0]**2 * betax)  +
           (-2*element.M[0, 0]*element.M[0, 1] * alphax)  +
           (element.M[0, 1]**2 * gammax)
           )  /  det_x
        final_twiss['alphax'] = (
           (-element.M[0, 0]*element.M[1, 0] * betax)  +
           ((element.M[0, 0]*element.M[1, 1] + element.M[0, 1]*element.M[1, 0]) *
               alphax)  +
           (-element.M[0, 1]*element.M[1, 1] * gammax)
           )  /  det_x
        finalgammax = (1 + final_twiss['alphax']**2) / final_twiss['betax']

        final_twiss['betay'] = (
           (element.M[2, 2]**2 * betay)  +
           (-2*element.M[2, 2]*element.M[2, 3] * alphay)  +
           (element.M[2, 3]**2 * gammay)
           )  /  det_y
        final_twiss['alphay'] = (
           (-element.M[2, 2]*element.M[3, 2] * betay)  +
           ((element.M[2, 2]*element.M[3, 3] + element.M[2, 3]*element.M[3, 2]) *
               alphay)  +
           (-element.M[2, 3]*element.M[3, 3] * gammay)
           )  /  det_y
        finalgammay = (1 + final_twiss['alphay']**2) / final_twiss['betay']

        etax = final_twiss['etax']
        etaxp = final_twiss['etaxp']
        etay = final_twiss['etay']
        etayp = final_twiss['etayp']

        final_twiss['etax'] = element.M[0,0]*etax+element.M[0,1]*etaxp+element.M[0,5]
        final_twiss['etaxp'] = element.M[1,0]*etax+element.M[1,1]*etaxp+element.M[1,5]
        final_twiss['etay'] = element.M[2,2]*etay+element.M[2,3]*etayp+element.M[2,5]
        final_twiss['etayp'] = element.M[3,2]*etay+element.M[3,3]*etayp+element.M[3,5]

        final_twiss['phix'] = sum_phix
        final_twiss['phiy'] = sum_phiy

    return final_twiss
```

I'll be very thankful if you can figure out the problem and explain it to me.

Comment: Apparently, `element.M` is `None`, but this depends on what `element` is. Please show a sample of `element`.

Comment: Interestingly the line raising the `TypeError` does not contain the first call to `element.M` but there are plenty of others before (apparently succeeding). It would be really helpful to know the types of `element` and `element.M`.

Comment: I've added some more text may be it will be helpful.

Comment: The branch you are showing (K<0) appears to make absolutely certain that `.M` is not `None`. Maybe have a look at `DriftMmat` and make sure it does contain `return` statements at all exits? And then there is the (K>0) branch.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, DriftMmat return M matrix. I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: In the very last branch of that code block you  are assigning to `self.R`, not `self.M`. May that be a typo? What happens if you change R to M there?

Comment: Yes, that is just typo. Thank you to figure it out :)